# samba4 not building in Arch

Tags: linux, samba, arch-linux

```
cp bin/tdbtool bin/tdbdump bin/tdbbackup /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/bin
cp ./include/tdb.h /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/include
cp tdb.pc /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib/pkgconfig
cp libtdb.a libtdb.so.1.2.4 /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib
rm -f /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib/libtdb.so
ln -s libtdb.so.1.2.4 /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib/libtdb.so
rm -f /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib/libtdb.so.1
ln -s libtdb.so.1.2.4 /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/lib/libtdb.so.1
mkdir -p /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg/`/tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/src/bin/python -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(1, prefix='/opt/samba4/samba')"`
cp tdb.so /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg/`/tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/src/bin/python -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(1, prefix='/opt/samba4/samba')"`
/bin/install -c -d /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/share/man/man8
for I in manpages/*.8; do \
                /bin/install -c -m 644 $I /tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-samba4/pkg//opt/samba4/samba/share/man/man8; \
        done
/bin/install: cannot stat `manpages/*.8': No such file or directory
make: *** [installdocs] Error 1
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build samba4.
==> Restart building samba4 ? [y/N]
==> -------------------------------
==>c
```

Any ideas as what is causing my build to fail? I assume it's an issue with manpages I can't figure out exactly what package it is looking for that I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your version of [libtdb](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&arch=&repo=&q=tdb&maintainer=&last_update=&flagged=&limit=50) then recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the section 8 manpage doesn't exist...you could just try touch manpages/forgetthis.8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried posting a comment on [the AUR page](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=40043)?  The maintainer is usually able to help with those sorts of things.

The thing that usually gets me into trouble is not having an updated system.  You've `-Syu`ed today?